# com.google.android.gms.R$styleable not found after chaging name of package

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2

My app was running fine and the google map was also working.
I changed the package name from com.example.hellworld so that I can put it on play store to what I wanted it, updated the manifest also, changed the API Key accordingly.

All other activities in my app work fine. But when I open the Activity containing the map it throws this error.

```
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:227)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.imaginate.socioreport.SampleActivity.onCreate(SampleActivity.java:54)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
11-07 13:31:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32116):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 13:31:51.263: I/Process(32116): Sending signal. PID: 32116 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the package name associated with your google map key still having same package name i.e com.example.hellworld. and here you change the name of package.

Comment: did u genrate a new key?

Comment: yes i did...

anyways i created a new package and copied all the files and not surprisingly it worked....seems that eclipse missed something while renaming the packages or something like that...

Comment: dude fault was at your side,u didn't update prefrances i think.